# How to track callback function events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, events, callback, dom-events

I recently created a simple function for simple JavaScript events which do not need all the bells and whistles of `addEventListener`. All was well until I needed to track Events (outside of Internet Explorer). While `window.event` seems to work in IE and Chrome, Firefox and some other browsers did not implement it. I'm trying to figure out how to get the same results on this example below.

Currently this example works for "Test Button 2" which returns the event object. How can we fix the `addEvent` function to support the same behavior? I tried various option without any luck...

```js
function addEvent (type, object, callback) {
  if (typeof object[type] != 'undefined') {
    var existingFunctions = object[type];
    object[type] = null;
    object[type] = function () {
      if (existingFunctions) {
        existingFunctions();
      }
      callback();
    };
  }
}

var testButton1 = document.getElementById("test1");

function callBack(event) {
 alert(event);
}

addEvent('onclick', testButton1, callBack); // This returns 'undefined' :(

var testButton2 = document.getElementById("test2");

testButton2.onclick = function(event) {
 callBack(event); // This works. 
}
```

```html
<button id="test1">
Test Button 1
</button>

<button id="test2">
Test Button 2
</button>
```

Comment: There's no real life outside of "all the bells and whistles of `addEventListener`".

Comment: @Teemu Tell that to IE8 - Also, even Mozilla says this approach is OK: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener "Because it was essentially part of DOM 0, this method is very widely supported and requires no special cross–browser code; hence it is normally used to register event listeners dynamically unless the extra features of addEventListener() are needed."

Comment: @Teemu Yes I'm aware of that, but I also heard of other browser issues (e.g. Blackberry browser) with that polyfill since it's specific to IE. I was trying to keep things simple. I'm sure there is a way to fix this but maybe I'm also starting to push the limits of simplicity.

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette it says it's used - it doesn't say it's OK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of answers about using simplified custom event listener functions, I ended up going back to using a [addEventListener polyfill](https://github.com/nbouvrette/eventListenerPolyfill).

To make sure recent browsers don't load this script for no reasons, I'm conditionally loading it while still in `<head>` with this simplified conditional loader:

```
// Event listener methods for IE8.
if (!Element.prototype.addEventListener && !document.body) {
     document.write('<script src="addEventListener.js"></script>');
}
```